# Looking for the birth place of Michael Joseph Farrell

Tags: 20th-century, birth-records, ireland

I'm looking for the birth place of Michael Joseph Farrell, who according to family search died in 1981 in Chester and was born in April 1926.

He married Veronica M Kelly in Chester in 1956.

There are no Michael Joseph Farrells born in Chester (he was Irish or of Irish origin)  in 1926 and this is all the information I have for now. I am doing this research for a friend and they are starting with very limited information.

Without ordering the marriage certificate, is this a dead end as there seems to be too many results to accurately determine.

If I even had his mother's maiden name I would be set but it isn't on the death register on family search.

Comment: Buy the marriage certificate otherwise you're wasting your time.

Comment: @AdrianB38 you're probably right

Comment: Don't forget that he might originally have been O'Farrell.

Comment: @AdrianB38 thanks for the heads up

Answer (score 2):

There is a family tree on Ancestry.com that has a Michael J. Farrell who died in Chester in 1981. Born in Longford, Ireland in 1926. The only difference is the month; it gives September as the birth month. There was a Michael J. born in Granard in 1926 who fits for the man in the family tree. The tree is at https://www.ancestry.com/family-tree/person/tree/39961853/person/19432286966/story

Comment: Hi Tom, thanks for this. I think I'll go for Granard as the birth then. Does the page list his parents? I don't have Ancestry

Comment: The tree doesn't give his parent's name. You do have the correct d.o.b. as listed on the death cert. I will keep digging and see what I can find.